# Express-Session and Mongostore multiple deployment overlapping cookie error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, express-session

I am running two app instances on DigitalOcean.
One is on example.com and the other is at beta.example.com
I'm using mongostore with express-session and each site has a separate mongo database.
I would not like for a user to be able to  log into example.com and be logged into beta.example.com. These should be separate.

The problem is sometimes I can not login into beta.example.com at all due to conflict with the cookie from example.com.
When I delete the cookies for example.com, then it works.
Is there a way to configure this such that this issue does not happen?